# Add item to xml everytime form is submitted - xmlwriter PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, xmlwriter

I have an html form when submitted post values to a php file. those values are then read into xmlwriter like below

```
<?php 
$pastor= $_POST["Speaker"];
$title= $_POST["Title"];
$link= $_POST["podcasturl"];
$download= $_POST["Download"];
$podcastid= $_POST["Podcastid"];
$pubdate= $_POST ["Date"];

$xml = new XmlWriter();
$xml->openURI('podcast.xml'); 
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->startDocument('1.0'); 
$xml->setIndent(4); 
$xml->startElement("podcast");
$xml->writeElement('pastor', $pastor);
$xml->writeElement('title', $title);
$xml->writeElement('link', $link);
$xml->writeElement('download', $download);
$xml->writeElement('podcastid', $podcastid);
$xml->writeElement('pubdate', $pubdate);
$xml->endElement(); 
$xml->endElement();  
$xml->endDocument();
?>
```

This whole system works fine. It creates the xml as I need it to based on the form. What I cant figure out is how to make it add a new item to the xml every time the form is submitted as opposed to it overwriting the same entry each time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead. `XMLWriter` is not intended to modify existing xml. From the [XMLWriter introduction:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xmlwriter.php)

> This extension represents a writer that provides a non-cached, forward-only means of generating streams or files containing XML data.

Using `SimpleXML` you can do something like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("podcast.xml");
$podcast = $xml->addChild("podcast");
$podcast->addChild("pastor", $pastor);
$podcast->addChild("title", $title);
$podcast->addChild("link", $link);
$podcast->addChild("download", $download);
$podcast->addChild("podcastid", $podcastid);
$podcast->addChild("pubdate", $pubdate);

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
$dom->save("podcast.xml");
```

In order for this example to work the `podcast` xml elements should be wrapped in an element (see below) and the `podcast.xml' file should already exist. Although the latter can be overcome with a check before loading.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<podcasts>
  <podcast>...</podcast>
  <podcast>...</podcast>
<podcasts>
```

Comment: Could you suggest how to append new data to XML file like sitemap.xml for this                                                         [similar SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26691391/1786360) ?