# How to update this xml file with PHP XML reader & writer?

Tags: php, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I have the following sitemap XML which contains a list of URLs to be submitted for search engines. I took this example code from another SO answer.

```
// Init XMLWriter
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI(APPLICATION_PATH . '/sitemap.xml');

// document head
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$writer->setIndent(4);
$writer->startElement('urlset');
$writer->writeAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');

// Write something
// this will write: <url><loc>some url here;  SO not allowed me</loc></url>
$writer->startElement('url');
$writer->writeElement('loc', 'some url here; SO not allowed me');
$writer->endElement();

// end urlset
$writer->endElement();
// end document
$writer->endDocument();
```

This code creates a new sitemap using XML writer. I want to append new url to existing urlset using XMLReader

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
if (!$reader->open('sitemap.xml')){
    die("Failed to open 'sitemap.xml'");
}
while($reader->read()){
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'urlset') {
        $writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $writer->startElement('url');
        $writer->writeElement('loc', 'http://www.test.com');
        $writer->endElement();
        break;
    }
}
$reader->close();
```

I could not find proper samples on how to update xml file with XMLreader. How can I rewrite this code so that it appends new URLs to url set tag using XMLreader?

**Edit 1:**

I have this xml sitemap,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urls>
    <url>
     <loc>http://www.bbc.com</loc>
    </url>
</urls>
```

I want the program to add one new url at the **urls** tag like this eg. adding URL  **google.com**,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urls>
    <url>
     <loc>http://www.bbc.com</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
     <loc>http://www.google.com</loc>
    </url>
</urls>
```

How could I get this functionality or is there some other helpers like **DOMDocument** or **simplexml** to do that in PHP? Any references to others sites is also welcome.

Comment: I need to open the sitemap.xml using XMLReader, create new url listing and append to existing urlset, then save XML file and close the connection.

Comment: You can edit your question to clarify bits.

Comment: Maybe, but you just keep posting comments instead of making edits.

Answer (score 1):

XMLWriter is not good for this methodology. You should use a different library, like simplexml for instance.

With that, it's very simple. Although I don't know what your doc structure looks like, let's take a stab at it:

```
//load the file for our manipulating
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

//grab the parent element that we want to append to
$urls = $xml->urls;

//add a new child called Url
$newUrl = $urls->addChild('url');

//add a new child called loc to the new child Url we just created, add a link to yahoo
$newUrl->addChild('loc', 'http://www.yahoo.com');

//write the output
$xml->asXML($xml);
```

[Here's an eval.in example](https://eval.in/215919c)

Comment: Thanks, good answer. But I just heard today that simpleXML loads full XML file into memory and depress efficiency. consider in case that the XML file contains 40,000 URLs, it has to load every thing into memory before updating the XML. What do you think?

Comment: @webblover Yep..this is true. I'll find a different approach given those circumstances. Give me a few minutes. :)

Answer (score 1):

I waiting for a good response, I have the some problem (xml file with over 50.000 elements) and I would like to add element without load full xml in memory